# Topological Homogeonity of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I wish to show that for every two points $x, y$ in the open unit ball $B_1(0)$ of $\mathbb R^n$ there exists a homeomorphism of the closed
unit ball $\overline{B_1(0)}$ which maps $x$ to $y$ and which fixes the boundary $\partial B_1(0)$ pointwise.

How can I do it? What do you introduce for it as references?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first assume we have $\lambda x =y$ with $\lambda >0$. Then the map $z \mapsto |z|^s x$ with $x=\ln(\lambda)/\ln (|x|)$ does the job.

In the general case we want to rotate $y$ to $y'$ such that we find a $\lambda >0$ with $\lambda x =y'$ to apply what we just did. Compute the angle you need to rotate and let the rotation angle approach zero when $|z|$ approaches $1$.

Comment: You haven't dealt with the case $x=0$. (Of course this is a bit silly: all you need now is a homeomorphism that moves $0$ *anywhere else* and fixes the boundary.)

Comment: @MikeMiller That's true. For that you have to find one map which fixes the boundary pointwise but brings $0$ to any other position. Then we are in my case.

Comment: Now one can do this by looking inside a ball centered close to, but not at, zero, and doing the same business again. If one wants all these maps to be diffeomorphisms they just need the rotation angle to be 0 before one reaches the boundary.

Comment: @MikeMiller Can you explicitly state such a map which fixes the boundary pointwise but brings $0$ to another position?

Comment: Let $f$ be a diffeomorphism $B^n \to B^n$, identity near the boundary, that moves $(.1, 0, \dots, 0)$ to some other point; say, uh, $(-.1,0, \dots, 0)$. Then linearly identify the ball $B((-.1,0,\dots,0),.2)$ with $B^n$, and act by $f$ in this ball, and the identity outside it. This is again a diffeomorphism (because $f$ was the identity near the boundary), identity near the boundary, that sends $0$ to $(-.2,0,\dots,0)$.